# How do I generate a random number in java between 450 and 150 that is a multiple of 10?

Tags: java, random

So far I have this code

```
int w = (int)((450-150)*random()+150);
```

This generates a number between 450 and 150... But I have no idea how to make that number a multiple of 10.

Comment: OMG. It looks like bunch of answers. :)

Comment: @Greg D - There's nothing about this that smells like homework to me. Besides, this is far from a "give me teh codez" question. The OP obviously has something working...just needed the last step. Certainly no reason to bring back the 'smells-like-homework' tag again.

Comment: yes it is homework... Is there something wrong with that considering I am showing I did some of my own work?

Comment: @Cheesegraterr: no. But marking it as such can help inform answerers, who may be kind enough to include additional explanation or ask leading questions to better help you understand the subject matter which this assignment was intended to teach you.

Comment: @Cheesegraterr - No. There's nothing wrong with that considering you obviously gave it a good shot but you should still tag it as homework so the rest of us know. You'll probably get much better explanations as to WHY we're giving you the code we are if you mention that it's homework, you're stuck, and you show that you gave it some real effort.

Comment: Typically, homework is tagged with a "homework" tag, as advice is given differently when is assigned as homework.  First, depending on your institution, there may be attribution/plagiarism issues with taking code directly from a forum and putting it in an assignment.  Second, programming assignments often encourage the programmer to try different programming techniques to accomplish a task, and that trial and error is crucial to the learning process.

Comment: Ya Cheesegraterr, aside from the fact you didn't explicityly state this is homework, I'd say you presented this correctly and asked for the right amount of help. It also helps if you provide your logic for why you think your solution works or doesn't work, as it will help people teach you the concept, like Shog9 said. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: between 450 and 150 INCLUSIVE?  for example, do you need the values 150 and 450 in the results set?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will be sure to tag it next time! I appreciate the help.

Comment: The link someone posted earlier is a dupe. Here's the [actual homework FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: @Justin:  I use [smells-like-homework] as a fun suggestion that a homework tag may be appropriate.  If the OP says that it isn't homework and removes the tag, that's fine.  If it's turned into [homework], that's the point and it's done its job.  (It was pretty obviously homework.  :) )  It certainly isn't rude and it doesn't suggest a "plz-send-teh-codez" question.  I give those a [plz-send-teh-codez] tag or I just vote to blow 'em away altogether.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy. Just generate random numbers between 15 and 45...then multiply by 10:

```
int w = ((int)((45 - 15) * random() + 15)) * 10;
```

Comment: How is this the correct answer? Since it multiplies by 10 before truncating to an integer, it doesn't produce multiples of 10.

Answer (score 11):

Pick a random number between 45 and 15 and multiply it with 10 -

```
int w = (int)((45-15)*random()+15) * 10;
```

Answer (score 7):

This smells like homework, but I'll bite:

Instead of starting from wide range of random numbers and them limiting the result, consider starting from a narrow range of numbers and expanding the result.

Your code must generate one of about 30 values, right?  So try generating a random value between 0 and 30, then transforming that value into the range you need.

(I'd suggest multiplying by 10 and adding 150.)

Comment: +1: IMO, this is the clearest way to characterize the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just pick a random integer between 15 and 45, then multiply it by 10:

`int w = 10*(int)((45-15)*random()+15);`

Answer (score 1):

If, as I suspect, the OP needs an inclusive range on both ends:  needs both the numbers 150 and 450, there is a range error on the answers I've seen so far.

Math.random() returns a number between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive).  If you want a number between 15 and 45 (both inclusive) your range of values is actually (45 - 15 + 1)... ie: a total of 31 values.

The correct code should be:

```
int w = ( (int)(((45 - 15 + 1) * random()) + 15) ) * 10;
```

(45 - 15 + 1) * random()  =  [0.0..30.999999)
[0..31) + 15  =  [15.0..45.999999)
(int)[15.0..46.0)  =  [15..45]  - integer conversion is a truncation, not a rounding
[15..45] * 10  =  {150, 160, 170, 180, ..., 440, 450}